# error al convertir de date a string en visual basic

Tags: visual-studio, vb.net

el codigo solo esta bien pero en otros equipos me aparece el error
eh intentado de varias maneras con .tostring("dd/MM/yyyy") con .ToShortDateString convirtiendo a string pero repito este error solo es visible en otros equipos eh verificado si el formato regional es el mismo y en efecto es el mismo incluso cambiando el tipo de dato a date pero aun aparece este error

```
Dim fecha As String
fecha = CStr(Date.Now.Date)
```

El error que aparece es el siguiente:

error al convertir una fecha y/u hora en cadena de caracteres

Comment: Hola! Bienvenido a SOes. ¿Cuál es el error? Por favor, edita tu pregunta y añade el mensaje completo de error, como texto.

Comment: El código que muestras no lanza ninguna excepción. Tendrás que aclarar exactamente el código que usas y que excepción te da

Answer (score 0):

' Intenta No Llamar Dos Veces a Date en la Misma Orden... Además de Crear una Variable
' de Fecha Para Tal Efecto, Después lo Asignas Así

Dim F As Date = Now

Dim fecha As String = CStr(F)

MsgBox(fecha)